# Flight with transfer

Tags: usa, luggage, airport-transfer

I will have booked s flight from Los Angeles to Düsseldorf via Newark. What happens with the baggage? Do I have to pick it up in Newark? And do I have to leave the security area in Newark?

Answer (score 0):

If flights are booked on the same PNR, then you have a good probability that the baggage will be automatically transferred. If they are not on the same PNR and not the same airline, then this is less likely to happen.